# Weird flickering from video source as texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, video, reflection, emission

My rendered animation has a weird flickering in it specifically from a video source used as texture and emission. It kind of looks like the first frame of the video is being rendered every few hundred frames and I have no idea why or even how this could happen. It seems to run just fine in the viewport.

The scene is a television with a video as the texture and emission reflected in a mirror.

Rendered in cycles at 30fps.

Video showing flickering
https://youtu.be/Y748GOFkEqw

Pictures show node tree
[image: node tree for texture]

Does anyone know why this is happening or how I might correct this?

Comment: Share your file using https://blend-exchange.com/ so we can help you

Comment: First Aid is - try to export video as image sequence and try to use it as source ... if it will solves the issue it is probably some codec issue.

Comment: I tired an image sequence and it rendered correctly, ty!